# How to load pickle files with a pytorch dataloader memory efficient?

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, pytorch-dataloader

I currently load data with `torch.load()` because it is saved as pickle. Pickle can only load everything at once into the memory. The dimension of the data is `[2000, 3, 32, 32]`.
Can I write a dataloader, where data is loaded subsequently? I have limited CPU memory and all at once would be too much.

I give an example:

```
data = torch.load('clean_data.pkl')
test_loader = dataloader(data, batch_size=32, shuffle=True)

result = []
for img, label in test_loader:
    # do somehting
    result.append([img.gpu()])

torch.save(result)
```

Well, when I write a data loader, I also need to use `torch.load`. By my understanding, the data loader would also open the pickle file all at once, right? So, I don't have no memory advantage.

What to do, to just load one file / batch after another, instead of the the whole pickle at once?

I have found a similar thread, here: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/loading-pickle-files-with-pytorch-dataloader/129405

https://localcoder.org/how-to-load-pickle-file-in-chunks
[How does one create a data set in pytorch and save it into a file to later be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49987614/how-does-one-create-a-data-set-in-pytorch-and-save-it-into-a-file-to-later-be-us)

I am grateful for any help. Thanks

Comment: I found this: https://github.com/UniNE-CHYN/mmappickle